# Questions about university student titles

Tags: phrases

I'm applying to abroad universities and I'm having some doubts on how to refer to myself.

I'm studying Business Administration (bachelor level). What of the following options sound better?

> "I'm a business bachelor student"
>   "I'm a business administration student"
>   "I'm a bachelor in business student"
>   "I'm a bachelor of business student"

Actually, I don't like how any of those sounds... could you please correct me or recommend better ways?

Comment: I think "business administration student" is the best of the choices you offered. Another option would be "undergraduate, studying business administration".

Comment: 'Abroad' is not used prenominally.

Comment: An undergraduate isn't a bachelor.  A bachelor is "one who has taken the first or lowest degree at a university, who is not yet a master of the Arts" (OED).  You don't become a bachelor until you complete your bachelor's degree.  Still, even if you had completed the degree, you wouldn't say "I'm a bachelor".  It would be too open to misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> I'm a business major

or

> I'm majoring in Business Administration

Comment: It depends on where OP is applying.